# Nice way to select a tuple using JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, generics, jpa, jpql

```
final List<Tuple> data =
                    em.createQuery("SELECT p.id AS i, p.membership AS m FROM Player p WHERE p.id IN :ids", Tuple.class)
                    .setParameter("ids", ids)
                    .getResultList();
```

This gives the error "`Cannot create TypedQuery for query with more than one return`". I could work around that by leaving out the type parameter (and using Object[] instead of Tuple, as I later found out):

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
final List<Object[]> data =
                    em.createQuery("SELECT p.id AS i, p.membership AS m FROM Player p WHERE p.id IN :ids")
                    .setParameter("ids", ids)
                    .getResultList();
```

But is there a solution that doesn't require unchecked code?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36089254/363573

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A tuple isn't really any more typesafe than an array, is it?

What you could do here is use a constructor expression. Off the top of my head, this is something like:

```
class PlayerMembership {
    public final int id;
    public final MembershipType membership;
    public PlayerMembership(int id, MembershipType membership) {
        this.id = id;
        this.membership = membership;
    }
}

List<PlayerMembership> data =
                    em.createQuery("SELECT NEW nl.bart.PlayerMembership(p.id, p.membership) FROM Player p WHERE p.id IN :ids", PlayerMembership.class)
                    .setParameter("ids", ids)
                    .getResultList();
```

This requires you to write a new class to hold the result, but this will typically be pretty trivial.

Comment: This is what I did, though I don't remember where I found it.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think so, except using the criteria API.

But really, the type-safety and correctness of the code depends much more on the query passed to `createQuery` than on the type of the list returned by the query. Moreover, you'll have to cast every element of the array anyway.

The SuppressWarnings annotation is the the last thing I would care about. The only thing that will really make the code type-safe is an automated test that executes the query and the code which consumes the result.

Comment: +1  The "type safety" of Tuple comes from the Criteria API itself.