# In JPA, relational databases and etc., What is a Tuple?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa

I'm studying Hibernate and JPA, and I am finding this term all the time. Could someone explain me in a practical and didactic way, what is this term, and how it relates to JPA / Hibernate / Databases ?

I wonder if it's a type of data structure that contains any type of data, but I'm not sure if it is really so. Also, I do not know its relation in a query with JPA... can anyone give me some light?

### EDIT

Guys, do not precipitate. I have searched on google, in a [dictionary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/tuple?s=t) (english), in wikipedia, here in the community (stackoverflow), and also the JPA Tuple API.

Here are some of my search terms:

- What is Tuple
- Tuple
- Databases Tuples
- JPA Tuple

All the documentation of the Java EE 6 says about Tuple is as follows:

> Interface for extracting the elements of a query result **tuple**.

That explains "A LOT".

I can not find something concrete, solid, concise, really explaining what it is. It is difficult for some mortals like me, born not knowing everything. I do not speak English natively, I do not have access to the entire contents of the universe, and sometimes I try to make this community the most practical, simple, friendly, and respectable in questions and answers. It's never enough. Do not presume that I did not research anything before coming here, that I am ignorant, lay, lazy or etc. This is preconception!

For the love of God... I use a translator to write, and I do not have practical understanding about certain things that for others is so easy to understand. My question even follows the rules for questions imposed here on stackoverflow. It's always something when I ask something. When I try to give answers, I always try to research before, and respond as best I can to other users. Give me some remorse sometimes participate in some communities... I ask for **knowledge**, not for status, and I'm sure others may have the same questions I have. Often people treat this community like a taboo, and not as a place to exchange knowledge. Again... for the love of God...

Comment: You can easily enough search on the web where it's amply explained in a computing sense. The JPA specific class is https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Tuple.html

Comment: sometimes, for those of us whose native language is not English, tuple as a name often misleads. me, I constantly mix it up with a KeyValuePair - because I e.g. there are words "triple", "quadruple" - so it was kind of natural for me to suppose that tuple is a sequence of exactly two values. well, it is not :/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Tuple is a generic term taken from mathematics, which just means "several values in specific order". If you can say "give me 2nd value of this thing" then the thing is a tuple.

There is no single notation for them, but you can imagine that `(1,2,3)`, `("a","b","c")` and `("John", "Smith", 12, false)` are all examples of tuples, having respectively 3, 3 and 4 items. Note that the idea of tuple puts no restrictions on the values, so they can have different types.

Technically a `List`, `String[]` and `Vector` are all tuples. But in languages like Java, the term is used mostly when the items are of different types - otherwise we talk about sequences.

In libraries like JPA the term is used interchangebly with terms *record* and *row*. Tuples can be represented by special classes, but one way often used in Java is just to have an `Object[]`.

Comment: Thanks for your response and attention @fdreger. I really appreciate your help. Now I can continue studying. Thank you.

Answer (score 17):

As was said, a `Tuple` is an ordered list of things. It helps to understand *why* you would use such a thing. Consider that you have a table in the database and for whatever reason you only want to select some of the columns from that table. From such a query you can get Objects and Tuples. Example, consider an Entity that has two fields, `latitude` and `longitude`:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id @GeneratedValue private Long id;

    private BigDecimal latitude;
    private BigDecimal longitude;
```

When you want to query **only** the latitude and longitude columns, where do you put the results? One of the ways to do it is to use `Tuples`:

```
// With objects, the alias information is lost.
List<Object[]> s = em.createQuery("select u.lattitude as lattitude, u.longitude as longitude from User u", Object[].class).getResultList();
s.stream().forEach((record) -> {
    System.out.println(record[0]+","+record[1]);
});

// With Tuples, the alias information is retained.
List<Tuple> t = em.createQuery("select u.lattitude as lattitude, u.longitude as longitude from User u", Tuple.class).getResultList();
t.stream().forEach((record) -> {
    System.out.println( record.get("lattitude") +","+record.get("longitude"));
});
```

As you can see, `Tuples` have an `alias` property that gets filled out by the query, which you can then use later. This is more convenient than an `Object`. Also, `TupleElement` supports Java Generics, so you can also have more type safety than you can have with `Objects`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will consider the response of the user @fdreger as correct for two reasons: That he had given me a solid foundation on the term, and he answered before. But you answered the second part of my question on how the term is related to others, and therefore, I can not fail to consider for your help as well. Thank you. Thank you, really.

Comment: Hi, We have Spring 4.3.18, Hibernate 4.2.18 and JPA 1.11.18 in our project, we have same issue, we need to execute a native oracle query, and map it to a DTO object. I can use transformer of Hibernate but we think that getting jpa Tuple from the query without hibernate intervention and map it manually to the DTO would be better for performance. but We receive this error from Hibernate since it is configured in JPA entity manager as JPAVendorProvider. the error is: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: `javax.persistence.Tuple`

Comment: this is the right answer, the difference between object array is crucial.