# Java getting data from a database with an SQL statement

Tags: java, sql

so I have data in a table that's initialized on startup in my configbean. 
The format is: String id, String name, Double rate
example: "1", "Alabama", .02

In my request bean, I have a function to get ONLY the names.

```
public List<String> getStateNames() {
    List<String> results = em.createNamedQuery("getStateNames").getResultList();
    results.sort(null);
    return results;
}
```

Here's the base file StateTax

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STATE_TAXES")
@NamedQueries({
/*@NamedQuery(
    name = "getTaxRate",
    query = "SELECT t FROM StateTax t WHERE t.stateName = :stateName"),*/
 @NamedQuery(
    name = "getStateNames",
    query = "SELECT t FROM StateTax t ORDER BY t.stateID")
  })
public class StateTax implements Serializable {
@Id
private String stateID;
private String stateName;
private double taxRate;

//supposed to lok like book.java
public StateTax() {

}

public StateTax(String id, String st, double tax) {
    this.stateID = id;
    this.stateName = st;
    this.taxRate = tax;
}

public String getStateID() {
    return stateID;
}

public void setStateID(String stateID) {
    this.stateID = stateID;
}

public String getStateName() {
    return stateName;
}

public void setStateName(String stateName) {
    this.stateName = stateName;
}

public double getTaxRate() {
    return taxRate;
}

public void setTaxRate(double taxRate) {
    this.taxRate = taxRate;
}



public String getState() {
    return stateName;
}

public void setState(String state) {
    this.stateName = state;
}

   @Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (stateID != null ? stateID.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    if (!(object instanceof StateTax)) {
        return false;
    }
    StateTax other = (StateTax) object;
    return this.stateID != null || this.stateID == null 
            && other.stateID == null || this.stateID.equals(other.stateID);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "bookstore.entities.StateTax[ stateId=" + stateID + " ]";
}
}
```

The end product is supposed to be a drop down box that allows you to select one option in xhtml.

My xhtml portion (which is commented out for now):

```
<h:outputLabel for="stateOption" value="#{bundle.StateName}"/>
            <h:selectOneMenu id="stateName"
                             required="true"
                            valueChangeListener="#{cashierBean.setTax}"> 
                <f:selectItems value="#{cashierBean.stateNames}"
                               var="stateName">                                
                </f:selectItems>
            </h:selectOneMenu>
            <h:message styleClass="error-message" for="stateOption"/>
```

So here's a part of the error I get on the SQL statement in my statetax file:

```
Exception Description: Problem compiling [SELECT t FROM StateTax t ORDER BY t.stateId].
```

My question: How do I properly get a list of names from a table?

Comment: Could you share all code for StateTax class

Comment: @MykhailoMoskura I added it in.

Comment: Exception Description: Problem compiling [SELECT t FROM StateTax t ORDER BY t.stateId
Your exception says problem compiling because of field name which you are invoking in JPQL
Actually as i see now it is stateID but was stateId

Comment: It is now working fine or you are having different error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nice way to select a tuple using JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668183/nice-way-to-select-a-tuple-using-jpa)